# Can't add custom font to python with fpdf on linux

Tags: linux, pyfpdf

I developed a software on my windows machine with `fpdf2` for python.
It worked perfectly, but now I have to install this program on a Red Hat Linux server and when I try to add custom font to pdf it throws an error: `cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system`

the code:

```
pdf = FPDF()
FONT_REGULAR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "fonts", "arial.ttf")
pdf.add_font("Regular", "", FONT_REGULAR, uni=True)
```

At this line it throws an error:

```
<NotImplementedError> "cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system"
```

Is there a workaround to this?

fpdf2 version: 2.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded to the latest version `2.5.1` and it works with linux also.